# Filter just keeps saying Loading

Tags: extjs, ext.net

We use Ext.Net runtime version 4.0.30319.
In one of our environment, when we try to filter the values in columns Broker or Custodian, it just keeps saying Loading, and the list of Broker or Custodian never comes up.
The same code works in another environment (the list of Broker or Custodian shows up).

Why in that 1 environment, the list doesn't show up, instead it just keeps saying Loading ?
Thank you.

Here are the codes.

```
X.Viewport().Layout(LayoutType.Fit).Items(
X.TabPanel().ID("ArchiveTabPanel")
.Items(
        X.GridPanel().ID("GridPanel1").MarginSpec("1 1 1 1").Cls("cust-grid").Title("Archive Trade Tickets").Icon(Icon.ServerCompressed)
                    .Bin(
                            X.StoreForModel().ID("Store2").Parameters(p => p.Add(new StoreParameter("id", "App.HiddenId.getValue()", ParameterMode.Raw)))
                            .Proxy(X.AjaxProxy()
                            .Url(Url.Action("GetFilterCustodian"))
                            .Reader(Html.X().JsonReader().RootProperty("data"))
                            ).Sorters("value", Ext.Net.SortDirection.ASC)
                            , X.StoreFor<OurCompany.OurApp.Model.vTRADETICKET>().ID("Store3").Parameters(p => p.Add(new StoreParameter("id", "App.HiddenId.getValue()", ParameterMode.Raw)))
                                .Proxy(X.AjaxProxy()
                                .Url(Url.Action("GetFilterBroker"))
                                .Reader(Html.X().JsonReader().RootProperty("data"))
                               ).Sorters("value", Ext.Net.SortDirection.ASC)
                    )

               .Store(X.StoreForModel().ID("Store1")
                        .Parameters(p => p.Add(new StoreParameter("id", "App.TradeDate.getValue()", ParameterMode.Raw)))
                    .Proxy(X.AjaxProxy()
                            .Url(Url.Action("ReadData"))
                        .Reader(X.JsonReader().RootProperty("data"))
                )
                .RemoteSort(false).Sorters("perform_File_TimeStamp", Ext.Net.SortDirection.DESC)
                .RemotePaging(false).PageSize(10000)
                )

                .Listeners(ls =>
                {
                    ls.ItemContextMenu.Fn = "showMenu";
                    ls.ItemContextMenu.StopEvent = true;
                })

                .ColumnModel(
                X.Column().Text("BatchId").DataIndex("Perform_File_TimeStamp").Width(60).Hideable(false).Groupable(false).Align(Alignment.Center).Filter(X.StringFilter()),
                X.Column().Text("Match").ID("allocation_Match").DataIndex("Allocation_Match").Width(50).Align(Alignment.Center).Hideable(false).Groupable(false).Filter(X.ListFilter().Options("Yes,No")),

               X.Column().Text("Comments").DataIndex("Comments").Width(80).Hideable(false).Groupable(false).Filter(X.StringFilter()),

       X.Column().Text("Broker").DataIndex("Broker").Width(200).Hideable(false).Groupable(false).Filter(X.ListFilter().DataIndex("Broker").StoreID("Store3").LabelField("Value").IDField("Value")),
                X.Column().Text("Custodian").DataIndex("Custodian").Width(150).Hideable(false).Groupable(false).Filter(X.ListFilter().DataIndex("Custodian").StoreID("Store2").LabelField("Value").IDField("Value")),

                X.Column().Text("Primary Contact").DataIndex("Primary_Contact").Width(150).Hideable(false).Groupable(false).Filter(X.StringFilter()),
                X.Column().Text("Main Phone").DataIndex("Main_Phone").Width(95).Hideable(false).Groupable(false).Filter(X.StringFilter()).Align(Alignment.Center),
                X.Column().Text("Phone").DataIndex("Phone").Width(95).Hideable(false).Groupable(false).Filter(X.StringFilter()).Align(Alignment.Center),
                X.Column().Text("By").DataIndex("Maintained_By").Width(80).Hideable(false).Groupable(false).Filter(X.StringFilter()).Align(Alignment.Center)
        )
```

Comment: Thats pretty funky code!! Have you written it yourself?

Comment: No, someone else wrote it. Funky good or bad ?

Comment: Good. Pretty hi-fi!

Comment: I found the problem. There was a problem with the result from the stored procedure that was just changed in this 1 environment. After the stored procedure is modified, the list now comes up. Thank you.